# Tkinter - create new window on top of root window

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I create a new tkinter root window on top of the main root window that prevents you from accessing the main window until you close the secondary window?

Here is the code that I've written so far (in python 3.6):

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x400+0+0')

def new_page():
    rootB = Tk()

btnNP = Button(root, padx=1, pady=2, fg='black',relief='raise',font=
('garamond',10, 'italic', 'bold'),
             text='New Page', bg='blue', command=new_page)
btnNP.place(x=100, y=300)

text1 = Text(root, bd=5, height=1, width=14, bg='pink')
text1.place(x=100, y=250)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try to share *why* that code doesn't work: does it not do what you want, or does it give an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Toplevel instead of a new root

```
def New_page():
    popup = Toplevel()
    popup.grab_set()
```

this should do the trick

Comment: It does the same thing just like my codes. I want it to work like a messagebox that prevent users to access the main root until exit the secondary screen.

Comment: when I use it in my program, I am unable to interact with any of the widgets within the original root. I would consider this preventing access

Comment: No problem. If you could mark my answer as correct that would be great :D

Comment: The docs have an example that will prevent access to the main window until the popup window is closed.  Scroll down to "Rolling your own".  https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html